# Mysql join problem between 5tables

Tags: mysql, join, isnull

Sorry for my english, I'm from austria, but I couldn't find another nice q&a-board. :)

I have a very strange structured mysql-database.
First there is a table for users, for my example there are only three colums interesting:

```
id, name, email
```

- My second table is a table for events: id, name
- My third table is a category-table for events: id, name, eventID
- My fourth table is a undercategory-table for events: id, name, catID
- My fifth table is a time-table for events: id, name, ucatID
- My sixth table is a table, where a entry combines a time with a person

Its a plan for work, in some way...

1. users: id, name, email
2. events: id, name
3. categories: id, name, eventID
4. undercategories: id, name, catID
5. underundercategories: id, name, ucatID
6. table to join: id, userID, uucatID

Yeah I have, so far, every entry `(user-name, ucat-name, uucat-name)` ...
but I'm trying to get a list of persons who have no entry in the join-table! (but only, where the eventID is ... say 1^^)

Here is my code for the list where there is an entry:

```
SELECT a.*,b.name,c.name AS zeit,d.name AS kategorie
FROM intern_user AS b
INNER JOIN intern_dienstplan AS a ON a.userID=b.id
INNER JOIN intern_events_uucat AS c ON a.uucatID=c.id
INNER JOIN intern_events_ucat AS d ON c.ucatID=d.id
INNER JOIN intern_events_cat AS e ON d.catID=e.id
WHERE e.eventID='".$_POST['eventid']."'
ORDER BY b.name ASC
```

I hope someone can help me... I have already tried something with "a.id is null" (where is no entry in join-table), but it doesn't work.

Comment: why don't you try a LEFT JOIN

Comment: No time right now to work this whole thing out as a complete answer but since you want to find entries in table 1 that are not in joined tables you should be having LEFT joins instead of INNER JOINS otherwise those rows won't be in the result at all. After that you do need checks like where e.id is null

Comment: I have tried a left join, but it didn't work either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time has gone... and I have found the solution for my problem. :]

Here the code, for others with the same problem...

```
SELECT *
FROM intern_user
WHERE 
(
    id NOT IN 
    (
            SELECT a.userID
        FROM intern_dienstplan AS a
        INNER JOIN intern_events_uucat AS b ON a.uucatID=b.id
        INNER JOIN intern_events_ucat as c ON b.ucatID=c.id
        INNER JOIN intern_events_cat AS d ON c.catID=d.id
                WHERE d.eventID='".$_POST['eventid']."'
        GROUP BY a.userID
        HAVING sum(b.wert) >= 100
    )
)
AND status='1'
```

Thanks for all help and have fun with this shit. :D

Greets

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is type of connection for categories-subcategories-subsubcategories.
How much subcategories could have the event (0-1-N)?

If you just want to find persons who do not have matched record in link table, you can use a query:

```
select a.*
from user a
left join link b on a.id = b.userId
where b.userId is null
```

or

```
select a.*
from user a
where id not in (select userId from link)
```

Update. Still do not have answer for the question above.
You can try:

```
select *
from users
where id not in (
    select link.userId
    from event a
    inner join categories ...
    inner join subcategories ...
    inner join categories ...
    inner join link ...
    where a.eventId = ...)
```

It could be easy transformed to versions with left join or exists().

Comment: That is something, that could help, but not in my situation, because in some time there will be a lot of events. And in the intern_dienstplan table will be lots of records from different events. With ur method, there would be only all users who haven't ever done a work in all the events, but I want only the people who haven't done a work in a specific event!

Comment: Okay I will try this later, but I will try it a different way, because this way it's not like I want it to be...

Comment: I have tested it and it works. Now, there is only one problem left!

This is the mysql_query:
SELECT *
   FROM intern_user
   WHERE id NOT IN 
   (
        SELECT a.userID
    FROM intern_dienstplan AS a
    INNER JOIN intern_events_uucat AS b ON a.uucatID=b.id
    INNER JOIN intern_events_ucat as c ON b.ucatID=c.id
    INNER JOIN intern_events_cat AS d ON c.catID=d.id
    WHERE d.eventID = '".$_POST['eventid']."'
   )

Now, I want to check, if ther is an entry in the link-table, if the "wert" (50% or 100% is possible) of all entries is >=100%!
the "wert" is in the table subsub-categories ...

Comment: wert is a % number..., without the %^^ every user needs to have 100% in sum of all records (or more)

Comment: and i want to have people/users: without any record (0%) or less than 100%!